# Qt QFileInfo::lastread() Windows (ntfs) dosn´t work need solution

Tags: windows, qt, filesystems

I Need to know if my file was accessed or not so I used QFileInfo::lastRead()...

That is what the docu said:

"On platforms where this information is not available, returns the same as lastModified()."

Is there any possibility to fix that for Windows (ntfs), or is there a list which holds all the filesystem types or systems for that QFileInfo::lastRead() works?

resp. is there any walkaround due sys/stat.h (?? I thought - works only for x16 and x32 ??)
i got x64 but I´m not sure.

Thank you in advance!

Matthias

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? How does the time value you get differ from what is indicated elsewhere such as windows file explorer?

Comment: QFileInfo::lastRead() Returns the time i´ve created the file...

Comment: not as expected! I expected to get the time of the lastModified() (i modified it :) but it is always the same value (the time i´ve created it)...

Comment: another question. Which steps did you do to test after the file creation? Did you read it, wrote in it, renamed it, etc..?

Comment: Oh the joy of interfaces providing information that's not usually even existing ... even UN*X-type filesystems that track access times (by high resolution - vs. Windows' filesystems access _dates_ only) will update the "access" timestamp at the same time as the "modified" timestamp. I.e. it's not possible to have "last read" as _older_ than "last written". I know of no filesystem in existance that tracks "last read" explicitly (vs. "last accessed" - for _either_ read, or write, or metadata updates / permission changes)